# How to get more information about an appengine outage if not a premium customer?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

We had an outage for our app shown on the dashboard below. There was no appengine outage notification and nothing on twitter so it looks like it was local to us. There was nothing noticeable in our logs (no increased failed requests, just silence). It lasted about 40 minutes and was noticed by our customers (we get about 1.5 requests per second). We are a paying customer but not premium (additional $500 per month) so can't email google about the issue. What's the best way to get more information / resolution of the problem?

[image: outage]

Comment: Do you just pay for the GAE or do you have an payed google apps account, too. Then you have email-support for that apps-account, and if you application is bound to this account, you might try it this way. But due to the internal structure of the gae its unlikly that an outage hits only you; are you sure that it wasnt a fault on you side (DNS-Server, Customer uplink, ..). Though we didnt noticed anything, if you tell me when exactly that outage was, ill could check our logs if our apps noticed some suspicious silence in that time, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to the app engine mailing lists.  There's usually a flurry of activity on the general one when !@#$ hits the fan.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-appengine

There's usually a message posted to on the downtime-notify list too, but it usually shows up after a bunch of people complain.  On the other hand, there's much less fluff to sort through.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/google-appengine-downtime-notify

In terms of resolution, you file a production issue (search for "production issue template" in that first mailing list), and wait.

Comment: Just received an email on the app engine downtime notify group. If you haven't yet subscribed, check the link below.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/l7sUFPypySU